# Data modelling: RBAC for small enterprise software

Tags: database-design

I'm building the core tables for a small, cloud-based enterprise app.

Is this data model suitable for a role based authentication system (flat hierarchy of permissions) that allows users to work for multiple companies?

[image: data model]

**Update**

As pointed out by Joel Brown, I didn't state my exact requirements. Here there are:

1. This app is for a startup and specs change quite often, so the model should be flexible and expandable. The underlying idea is to create enterprise software (think ERP).
2. One User can work for multiple Organizations with multiple Roles & Permissions (imagine a chain of hotels, each hotel is an Organization, and the top management of the chain has access to various Organizations)
3. Permissions can be flat (ie no hierarchy).

Comment: You don't state your exact requirements, so it is difficult to critique your model.  This model will work fine if all you need is to handle one or more role assignments per user where these roles can be in one or more organizations.  It is flexible insofar as it permits different role assignments for each organization.  Some people would question the need for `employments.id` since this table is a pure intersection and you could just as easily use a compound primary key for `employments`.  Some might point out that this could have performance benefits when checking user roles.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I updated the post. Having a 1:n relationship between User and Organization would not allow the User to work for multiple Organizations, correct?

Comment: Mike81 - Changing the primary key of `employments` to the combination of `users_id` and `organizations_id` doesn't change the relationships in any way.  The `employments` table is still a many-to-many intersection table, so each user can belong to many organizations and the role assignments for employees are still organization-specific.  It would mean propagating user and organization columns to your `role_assignments` table, which would allow direct joins for convenience.  Your FK constraint would from `role_assignments` would still be to `employments` though.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I read up on compound primary keys. Very interesting, I never heard about it before. Unfortunately, my framework (Rails) does not seem to support compound primary keys.